# Spark backtick for column names with a space causes an error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-synapse

Using Scala, I read a dataframe into memory using JDBC driver (I followed the example from here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/query-serverless-sql-pool-from-an-apache-spark-scala-notebook/ba-p/2250968). The data is in a Synapse SQL Serverless Pool with External Data in a Lake. One of the fields has a space in the name and while I can use the backtick symbol in the SELECT clause and the query executes successfully, I get an error when I do so in the WHERE clause.

```
%%spark
df1.createOrReplaceTempView('temp1')
df1 =  sqlContext.sql("""select `Customer Id` from temp1 where `Customer Id` = 100 """)

I also tried:
%%sql 
select `Customer Id` from temp1 where `Customer Id` = 100


Error: 
Syntax error at or near 'Id': extra input 'Id'(line 1, pos 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

While writing PySpark code we can use Backticks. But while write code in sql we can use either Square Brackets `[<column name>]` or double quotes `"<column name>"`

Comment: Try:

select [Customer Id] from temp1 where [Customer Id] = 100

Comment: [<column name>] Error:
Syntax error at or near '['(line 3, pos 6)

Table[<column name>] results in the same error:
Syntax error at or near 'ID': extra input 'ID'(line 3, pos 28)


"<column name>" comes back with no results even though I know there are results.

Comment: @DataAIWorld can you share the screen shot of code and the error message

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df2 =  sqlContext.sql("""select `Customer Id` from temp1 where "Customer Id" = 100 """)
```

Checking for double-quotes, if the backticks are not working.

However this is always complicated in different SQL notations. So I would suggest just rename the Spark Dataframe column with `withColumnRenamed(existingName, newNam)`. Just use an underscore or CamelCase: `CustomerId`

```
df2 = df1.withColumnRenamed("Customer Id", "CustomerId")
```

And then use df2 for the subsequent next operations:

```
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('temp2')
df3 =  sqlContext.sql("""select CustomerId from temp2 where CustomerId = 100 """)
```

Hope that helps!